# sound not working..... Play sound through list empty... help

Tags: sound, vlc

VLC shows this error

[image: vlc error image]

In sound settings... the 'play sound through' list is empty
[image: sound setting error]

how do i fix this issue

Comment: even i am facing the same problem. The sounds work till i reach the login screen or login as guest.